# Prometheus return nothing after while

Tags: monitoring, prometheus, grafana, metrics

We are using Prometheus and Grafana for our monitoring and we have a panel for response time however I noticed after while the metrics are missing and there are a lots of gap in the panel (only for response time panel) and they comeback as soon as I restart the app (redeploying it in openshift). the service has been written in Go and the logic for the gathering response time is quite simple.

we declared the metric

```golang
var (
    responseTime = promauto.NewSummaryVec(prometheus.SummaryOpts{
        Namespace: "app",
        Subsystem: "rest",
        Name:      "response_time",
    }, []string{
        "path",
        "code",
        "method",
    })
)
```

and fill it in our handler

```golang
func handler(.......) {
        start := time.Now()
        // do stuff
        ....

        code := "200"
        path := r.URL.Path
        method := r.Method
        elapsed := float64(time.Since(start)) / float64(time.Second)
        responseTime.WithLabelValues(path, code, method).Observe(elapsed)
 
}
```

and query in the Grafana panel is like:

```
sum(rate(app_rest_response_time_sum{path='/v4/content'}[5m]) / 
rate(app_rest_response_time_count{path='/v4/content'}[5m])) by (path)
```

but the result is like this!!
[image]

can anyone explain what do we do wrong or how to fix this issue? is it possible that we facing some kind of overflow issue (the average RPS is about 250)? I'm suspecting this because this happen more often to the routes with higher RPS and response time!

Comment: Do you see the same lines when you run the query in Prometheus?

Comment: No, the graph is same in Prometheus and Grafana

Answer (score 0):

Prometheus records the metrics continuously normally and if you query it, it returns all the metrics it collected for the time you queried.

If there is no metric when you query, that has typically three reasons:

- the metric was not there (it happens when the instance restarts and you have a dynamic set of labels and there was no request yet for the label value you queried (in your case there was no query for `path='/v4/content'`). In such case you should see other metrics of the same job (at least `up`).
- Prometheus had problems storing the metrics. (see the log files of prometheus for that timeframe).
- Prometheus was down for that timeframe and therefore did not collect any metrics. (In that case you should have no metrics at all for that timeframe.

Comment: I'd add to that list:
• Prometheus had problems scraping the metrics. If the instances were experiencing high load, is it possible that Prometheus did not finish it's scrape before timing out?